# Apache 2.4, Python and Django on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Windows 8.1. and trying to configure XAMPP (apache 2.4, VC11) to work with Python (I have 2.7) and Django (1.7). Have downloaded mod_wsgi (VC9), changed httpd.conf but still getting Apache shut down: Any clues?

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 06:24:31  [Apache]   This may be
>   due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  06:24:31  [Apache]
>     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   06:24:31  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   06:24:31  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 06:24:31 
>   [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this 06:24:31  [Apache]
>     entire log window on the forums

Comment: Edit your question and add what changes  you have made. How/where did you download mod_wsgi.

Comment: The mod_wsgi documentation at https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst does warn you against mixing objects compiled for different ABI versions. This is quite likely the cause. Try VC10 Apache instead, you may have more success. I don't know of anyone who has successfully used VC11 Apache with VC9 Python and mod_wsgi. Some have claimed VC10 Apache was okay though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python 2.7, Your Apache must be compiled with VC9, You can download the required Apache from - (https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx#APACHE24VC09).  Make sure you download the 32 bit version if you are running a 32 bit python installation or the 64 bit version if your python installation is 64 bit.